# Android PhoneGap - Access Plugin from Plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a application for Android with PhoneGap. I have several custom Plugins that are accesses from the front-end's JavaScript.

Now I need to axecute/call a method from a plugin from inside another plugin. Is there a way to access plugins from inside a plugin?

Example:

I have a tracking plugin that handles all kinds of tracking stuff. And then there is another plugin that displays a native android Dialog (and other stuff).
To avoid writing my tracking implementation twice (and also to avoid singletons) I want the JS code AND that plugin to use my tracking plugin.

tl:dr;

How to call a plugin's methods from inside another plugin.

Comment: It seems I can get the plugin via this.appView.pluginManager.getPlugin() from inside an activity or via this.webView.pluginManager.getPlugin() from inside another plugin.

After executing a request on that plugin, how do I get the results out of my callbackContext I sent with that request?

Comment: Could you just create an instance of your tracking class inside of your dialog plugin (assuming that your tracking logic has a class of it's own)?

Comment: I could do that. But it would have been convenient to allways use the same mechanics for tracking requests. No matter if called from the webpage's js or from inside another plugin or activity. Since Im now able to get a plugin (see above comment) i added a function in there to expose the tracking method directly in addition to the execute method. Similar to your suggestion.

Comment: Using a new instance as you suggested would either force me to use a singleton (bad for my unit tests) or loose my session id inside the tracking class.